# React Native - how to keep screen awake?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I found a module [react-native-keep-awake](https://github.com/corbt/react-native-keep-awake) for keep the screen awake for react native. However, seen like this module have some problem , i tried to `console.log(this.props.screenShouldBeAwake);` the value, it gave me `undefined`. Is there any other way to trigger the screen to be awake ?

Answer (score 4):

Now expo supports this feature. It's easy to use.

```
import { activateKeepAwake, deactivateKeepAwake } from 'expo-keep-awake';
// Prevents the screen from sleeping until deactivateKeepAwake is called with the same tag value.
activateKeepAwake("tag");
// Releases the lock on screen-sleep prevention associated with the given tag value. 
deactivateKeepAwake("tag");
```

See details in the [expo doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/sdk/keep-awake/)

Answer (score 0):

OK I have solution, hope to help others in the future.

1. import KeepAwake from 'react-native-keep-awake';
2. create a state and name it `keepawake` , or whatever you want.
3. create a arrow function to call when onPress

   ```
   changeKeepAwake = () =>{
      if(!this.state.keepawake){
        this.setState( prevState => ({keepawake: !prevState.keepawake}));
        KeepAwake.activate();
      }else{
        this.setState( prevState =>({keepawake: !prevState.keepawake}));
        KeepAwake.deactivate();
      }
   ```

   }
4. DONE